# Implementation of a Capacitor Plugin for Webgazer.js

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am currently working on a project working with [Webgazer.js](https://webgazer.cs.brown.edu/#).
With the help of [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/), [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) I got it to work on my laptop as a website and on my Android Smartphone as a Website and as a PWA.

Now to my problem/question:
I also tried to run it as a native Android App but there the Webgazer.js plugin is not working.
Did I understood it right that I would have to implement a Capacitor plugin as a translator from the Javascript code of Webgazer.js to native Android code or is there another way to run the app with native code and still use the Webgazer.js?

I am happy for every help I can get and I am open to any questions.

Kind regards
Lars

Comment: Webgazer.js uses tensorflow.js and the WebVideo API to retrieve the Camera output (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia). Did you make sure, that you have enabled Camera Access in the AndroidManifest and tried [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/use-getusermedia-in-capacitor/218807/6)?

Comment: This did work!! Can you maybe explain me why the Webgazer.js works when running as a native Android App? How does it do it?

Comment: What Do you mean by "why Webgazer.js works when running as a native Android App"?

Comment: Coming back here after some months and I am not 100% sure what I wanted you to explain. But just for information: webgazer.js in native Android Code makes the whole UI so slow that it really feels like it is a huge lag all the time. As a PWA there is no problem at all.

Comment: It might not be suitable for you, but another option would be to use mediapipes FaceMesh model, which also runs on react-native with tensorflow.js. You have to reimplement the gazetracking logic by yourself of course, but this would probably a much faster solution. The fastest solution would be to use tflite with the react-native-fast-tflite package. The Facemesh model for tflite can be found [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-assets/face_landmark.tflite). I hope that helps you a bit